# Unix command to convert character encoding in a .csv file

Tags: command, character-encoding

I need a Unix command to convert a .csv file that is in UNICODE format to ANSI format.

The file is imported from the Cognos environment and I am unable to make any changes with the format in cognos.

Answer (score 7):

You can use iconv to convert between encodings

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii oldfile > newfile
```

Answer (score 2):

- I noticed mine having similar issue but was not able to find what type of encoding it was.
- Notepad++ tells in my case that it was ANSI so the above command dint help me.
- Now there are many types of ANSI so the best way to check that was to type

  > *iconv -l*
- This lists all the encoding format names. So in my case I narrowed that to:

  > ```
  > *iconv -l|grep -i ansi
  > ANSI_X3.4-1968//
  > ANSI_X3.4-1986//
  > ANSI_X3.4//
  > ANSI_X3.110-1983//
  > ANSI_X3.110//
  > MS-ANSI//*
  > ```
- Since I dint know the specific ANSI I tried almost all of them until I found it was MS-ANSI - I should have known, since I received the file from a Microsoft system. So then I converted using this command:

  > *iconv -f MS-ANSI -t utf-8 sample.csv > sampleUTF8.csv*
- So in the same way list out the UNICODE types in iconv -l and reverse the order to get the ANSI type you desire and would be simple.

Comment: How does this apply to the question?